# closed subspaces of locally convex inductive limits

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, locally-convex-spaces

Let $\left(V_{n},\phi_{n,n+1}\right)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ be an inductive sequence of LCTV spaces. A locally convex inductive limit of $\left(V_{n},\phi_{n,n+1}\right)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$  is it's algebraic inductive limit $V=\lim_{\to}V_{n}$, equipped with final locally convex topology w.r.t. $\phi_{n}:V_{n}\to V$.

$V$  can also be described as a quotient of the locally convex direct sum $\bigoplus V_{n}$  by the subspace $D$ , generated by vectors $\left\{ \left(\dots,v_{n},-\phi_{n,n+1}\left(v_{n}\right),\dots\right)|v_{n}\in V_{n}\right\} $. We denote by $\pi:\bigoplus V_{n}\to V\simeq\bigoplus V_{n}/D$  the quotient map. The universal property of V  follows from the universal properties of $\bigoplus V_{n}$  and of the quotient.

A map $f:V\to U$  in LCTV is continuous iff maps $f\circ\phi_{n}$  are continuous. Taking $f=\mathrm{id}_V$   one get that if subspace $F\subset V$ is open (closed) then $F_n=\phi_{n}^{-1}\left(F\right)$  is open (closed). Clearly $F\cong\lim_\to F_n$ as linear space.

The question I am trying to understand is the following: if $F$ is a closed subspace, why it does not have to be the locally convex inductive limit of $F_n$ (why topologies can be different)?

We clearly have $\pi^{-1}(F)=\bigoplus F_n$, which is a closed subspace of $\bigoplus V_n$. Doesn't this force the quotient topology on $\pi^{-1}(F)/\pi^{-1}(F)\cap D$ (which is the locally convex inductive limit topology) be the subspace topology of $F$?

Would it matter if $V_n$ are Banach spaces?

Comment: Initial and final topologies don't in general play nice together. A subspace of a quotient is not necessarily homeomorphic to the quotient of the subspace. I'm almost sure that the $V_n$ being Banach spaces wouldn't change the phenomenon, but I'd have to check to be totally sure.

Comment: I don't quite understand your remark about initial topologies. Quotient topology is also a final topology, w.r.t the quotient map.

Comment: Yes, but the _subspace topology_ is an _initial topology_.